# Inject Spring bean into enum and invoke it inside enums functional interface

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, enums, functional-interface

Well I guess I am trying to achieve more than I can but I wanted to create an aggregator class for all my dictionary values in my application. Therefore I created an enum which would have two arguments - first being dictionary name and second being the `Supplier`. I went for `Supplier` because supplied value will be calculated for each dictionary differently. So far I came up with this:

```
public enum DictionaryAggregator {

    STATUS_X("statusX", StatusX::getDictionary),
    STATUS_Y("statusY", new Supplier<Map<String, ?>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, ?> get() {
            return <would like to reference to statusYCache which is inside DictionaryAggregatorServiceInjector>;
        }
    });

    private final String dictionaryName;
    private final Supplier<Map<String, ?>> dictionary;

    public String getDictionaryName() {
        return dictionaryName;
    }

    public Supplier<Map<String, ?>> getDictionary() {
        return dictionary;
    }

    DictionaryAggregator(String dictionaryName, Supplier<Map<String, ?>> dictionary) {
        this.dictionaryName = dictionaryName;
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    @Component
    static class DictionaryAggregatorServiceInjector {

        @Autowired
        private StatusYService statusYService;

    }
}
```

but whatever I tried I could not come up with an idea how could I supply values from `StatusYCache` service. Ideally what I would like to achieve is that the `Supplier` for `STATUS_Y` could easily invoke methods from `StatusYService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I should use my brain more frequently. I came up with this:

```
public enum DictionaryAggregator {

    STATUS_X("statusX", StatusX::getDictionary),
    STATUS_Y("statusY", new Supplier<Map<String, ?>>() {
        @Override
        public Map<String, ?> get() {
            return new StatusYDictionaryClass(DictionaryAggregatorServiceInjector.shipmentStatusVos).getDictionary();
        }
    });

    private final String dictionaryName;
    private final Supplier<Map<String, ?>> dictionary;

    public String getDictionaryName() {
        return dictionaryName;
    }

    public Supplier<Map<String, ?>> getDictionary() {
        return dictionary;
    }

    DictionaryAggregator(String dictionaryName, Supplier<Map<String, ?>> dictionary) {
        this.dictionaryName = dictionaryName;
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    @Component
    static class DictionaryAggregatorServiceInjector {

        static List<StatusYObj> statusYList;

        @Autowired
        public StatusYService statusYService;

        @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            statusYList = statusYService.getStatusYList();
        }

    }
}
```

It seems to be working.